# SpecFlow Test Cases are not displayed in Test Explorer using MSTest

Tags: c#, unit-testing, specflow

- I have created a **UnitTest** Project and added app.config as file it
  didn't come by default with the UnitTest Project and added NuGet
  package SplecFlow.MsTest.
- Then I have updated the Visual Studio SpecFlow for 2017 from `Tool>>Extensions` and Updates.
- Then added a specFlow feature file in it.

I can't see anything added to the `App.config` after adding the `SpecFlow.Mstest`. Ideally, it should add `<unitTest>MsTest</UnitTest>` tag in the config file. The default test case is not seen in Test Explorer. Sometimes it shows error as `"No test are found with`
`fullyQualifiedName=<SolutionNameandTestCase name>"`

1. Tried to go through the Setup

https://www.testautomationtribe.com/specflow-tutorial-c-project-setup

2. Tried with Class library project as well
3. Feature `file >> Properties >>Custom tool` to blank perviously it was `SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator`

Test Explorer should display the test cases.

Comment: Follow [this](https://specflow.org/getting-started/) guide instead. The tutorial you linked to seems out-of-date. You don't need app.config.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation nuget package and it should work.